# Variables not Initialized in Excel VBA Loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm back with another question in VBA.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w2fv716b65x4fp/Beer.xlsm?dl=0)'s the (updated) file I'm working on. When I try to run it, it says
`Run-time error '92': For loop not initialized`.

The loop is `For Each var In accepted` and I have already defined `var` and `accepted` as follows:

`Dim accepted() As Variant`

`Dim var As Variant`

`...`

`For Each var In accepted`

`...`

`Next var`

I'm not sure why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can't use a For Loop on an array with no dimensions defined.

So if your `accepted` array hasn't been (Re)Dim'ed to have an actual dimension before the Loop starts, you'll get that error.

Check out this StackOverflow question for some ways to deal with (potentially) non-dimensioned arrays:

- [VBA: Don't go into loop when array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874086/vba-dont-go-into-loop-when-array-is-empty)